# GitLab CI select runner based on whether branch is protected

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have two runners set up on a GitLab "group". One of the runners can only be used by "protected" branches. The other one can be used by any branch.

I want to set up a GitLab CI spec that selects the right runner based on whether or not the branch is protected.

What I have been able to do is to set tag on the two runners (lets say `runner-protected-branches` and `runner-feature-branches`) and then select them explicitly in the CI steps, e.g.:

```
my-job-protected:
  tags:
    - runner-protected-branches
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED== "true"
  script: |
    echo "running with runner-protected-branches"


my-job-feature:
  tags:
    - runner-feature-branches
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED== "false"
  script: |
    echo "running with runner-feature-branches"
```

In the above snippet, `my-job-protected` will run if the built-in variable `CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED` is true, and `my-job-feature` will run if it is false. In this way I can pick the correct runner. This feels very clunky though. Is there a better way I could do this? Is there a way for example to set a top-level variable and pass that in to the "tags" list? i.e. something like:

```
my-job:
  tags:
    - $TAG
  stage: build
  script: |
    echo "running with $TAG"
```

Comment: I think it’s a valid way to get this sort of thing to work. 

My question would more be on about it being clunky. Why you need this approach? Is there something different between the two runners or something different about a protected and unprotected branch that means they can’t just use the same runner?

Comment: Yes, we use different runners to deploy infrastructure to different environments. We use runners that are allowed to only run on "protected" branches to deploy to production, whereas test infrastructure can be deployed from other branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found out that it really is as easy setting a workflow-level env var and then using that as the tag, for example:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"
      variables:
        TAG: runner-protected-branches
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "false"
      variables:
        TAG: runner-feature-branches

my-job:
  tags:
    - $TAG
  stage: build
  script: |
    echo "running with $TAG"
```